# MySQL select max number of rows for each category

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm struggling to getting this query to work. I have 3 tables that needs to communicate with each other, to list all winners from a poll which has different categories.

Basic structure:

site_poll (main table, where the options for each poll goes):
ID (INT, Primary)
cat_id (INT)

site_poll_cat (table for each categorie)
ID (INT, Primary)
name (VARCHAR)

site_poll_votes (table for each piece of vote)
ID (INT, Primary)
vote_id (which is ID of site_poll)
user_id (INT)

What I want is to have a random list of 6 Winners, but one winner per category. The winner is defined by whoever gets more rows in the site_poll_votes table.

Here's the query that I came up with, but nothing appears:

```
SELECT MAX(maxvotes) AS votes
FROM
  (SELECT e.*,
      c.name,
      c.icon,
      r.icon AS radio_icon,
      COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(v.id)),0) AS maxvotes
FROM site_poll_votes v
INNER JOIN site_poll e ON v.vote_id = e.id
INNER JOIN site_poll_cat c ON e.cat_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN site_radios r ON e.radio_id = r.id
GROUP BY cat_id) q
GROUP BY cat_id
ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 6
```

NOTE: site_radios is another table, but is mainly for getting a radio station icon for each poll option; some columns are not specified in the strucutre I've shown, because they're mostly for design purposes.

Any help will be heavly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Desired behavior:

Let's say we have site_poll with these entries:

value: 98.1 FM, cat_id: 3 (4 votes in site_poll_votes)

value: 99.3 FM, cat_id: 3 (10 votes in site_poll votes)

value: John, cat_id: 2 (1 vote in site_poll votes)

value: Josh, cat_id: 2 (0 votes in site_poll votes)

What I want is that only 98.1 FM and John shows up, because they've got the most number of rows (votes). But let's imagine there are 10 categories, so I wan't it to display randomly so that 6 different categories with its winners shows up everytime.

Comment: Your query has some problems: you are selecting non aggregate columns  with `GROUP BY`, and you are also grouping twice for some reason.  Maybe showing some sample data and expected output would help.

Comment: Tim Biegeleisen question edited with an example of how I want it to work.